# oData service not returning CLOB field

Tags: oracle, odata

I have a simple Oracle table with 3 fields: ID (int), Name (nvarchar), and configJSON (CLOB).

The configJSON field is over 10,000 characters.

I am trying to use this table in an oData web service using entity framework.  I do not get an error message, but the response is simply blank.  When I remember the CLOB column I see the other 2 data fields so I think the issue relates to the large CLOB field.  I am not tied to that particular data type but I thought that was the best to use since my field is so large.

What is the best way to return a large data field within an oData web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the field type to a LONG.

Comment: The LONG data type has been deprecated for many releases. [Oracle says not to create new tables using it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201). It may have solved your current issue, but it isn't a good long-term fix. (Also, if you're using 12c a VARCHAR2 column can be 32k now, which may be enough - you haven't said which version you're using, though).